# uninitialized constant MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am getting the problem of `MiniMagick`

here is the description what i wants to need.

I am using the following gem for creating the QR code.

```
  gem 'rqrcode-rails3'
```

As that gem response me data of QR code in SVG format and i wants to create a PNG format image with following way.............

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.read(svg) { |i| i.format "svg" }
```

but it gives me error-

```
uninitialized constant MenusController::MiniMagick
```

I have following ruby and rails version.

```
ruby 1.9.2
rails 3.2.13
```

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
gem 'mini_magick'
```

to your gemile and run `bundle install`

Comment: Could you paste your gemfile? Also what environment are you getting this error on?

Comment: + Did you remember to restert the server/console?